# regular expression, negative look-around for wired email matching

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a email matcher, since there are so many things like this:

`https://site_1.com@site_2.com/xxxxx`

I decided to use a negative to get rid of these. My attempt is as follow:

`regex = r"([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+(?!https?://.*)@[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]\.[a-zA-Z0-9])"`

My idea is, the negative look-around will fail to match anything with a https://xxxxx@, but clearly I'm wrong. I did the following:

```
email_search = re.compile(regex)
email_search.search("https://siteA.com@siteB.com")
```

And the result is a match, the matched string is `//siteA.com@siteB.com`

I sort of have to use `re.search` because I'm working with obfuscated text, but the negative look ahead should do the trick in my understanding, please show me what I did wrong and how to do it correctly, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need regex? `"https://site_1.com@site_2.com/xxxxx".split('/')[2]` would do

Answer (score 1):

Use negative look-aheads to prevent certain inputs from matching (i.e. "preconditions"):

```
regex = r"(?!https?://)<actual email regex here>"
```

You can chain them:

```
regex = r"(?!<exclude this>)(?!<exclude that>)(?!<and that>)<actual regex here>"
```

Apart from that - so, so, *so* many email matching regexes have been made by now that I would discourage you from inventing yet another one. Pick one from the pile.

The better ones would not allow things like `https://site_1.com@site_2.com/xxxxx` from the start, so you would not have to work around defects in your own creation.